# Nested comprehensions in Elixir

Tags: python, elixir, list-comprehension

In Python, one can do this `[e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1)]`. What is the equivalent (and right) form of this construct in Elixir?

What I tried, is:

```
def edits2(word) do
  (for e1 <- edits1(word), do: edits1(e1))
  |> Enum.reduce(MapSet.new, fn(item, acc) -> MapSet.union(item, acc) end)
end
```

but this is awfully slow, since it happens I need to do a MapSet of hundreds of lists, each containing 500+ elements.

Comment: Is this faster: `for e1 <- edits1(word), e2 <- edits1(e1), into: MapSet.new, do: e2`?

Comment: @Dogbert unfortunatelly no. It still gets stuck.

Comment: How long does just returning the list take?

Comment: @Dogbert running a simple test gives me: ```$mix test
 ...
  * test replace 2
  * test replace 2 (282508.9ms)
  * test insert (skipped)
  
Finished in 282.6 seconds
6 tests, 0 failures, 4 skipped```

Comment: And how much time to create the MapSet in my code? It should take a negligible amount of extra time to create a MapSet of 100k terms compared to the 282 seconds for list.

Comment: @Dogbert the test run is for your code. My code was worse, so I stopped it after ~6-7 mins.

Comment: @Dogbert Here is the full code: https://github.com/visar/spell_check

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the anwser to my initial question is just what @Dogbert suggested: `for e1 <- edits1(word), e2 <- edits1(e1), into: MapSet.new, do: e2`

But the bottleneck wan't this particular line. See https://github.com/visar/spell_check/commit/857653593ca98310db028601e9cfc59dc1ac13a4?diff=split for some optimizations, which truncate the running time of the particular test to under 2s on my machine.

The killer was that `known/1` was recalculating the word keys every time - and there are thousands of them - but it could safely be a constant, so it takes a little longer to compile but it runs much faster.